# Where do I place the setCameraDisplayOrientaion method?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to figure out how to set the display orientation for the camera in my app, I am new to java coding and android so I am trying to figure out where I need to put the setCameraDisplayOrientation() method and also the proper flags that need to be passed inside of the parenthesis, any help would be great The Method for the setCameraDisplayOrientation is the last method at the bottom of the snippet

thank you!

```html
 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.hardware.Camera; 
import android.view.Surface; 
import android.view.SurfaceHolder; 
import android.view.SurfaceView; 
import com.ericsson.ejorsha.fsomobileapp.activities.CameraActivity; 
 
import com.ericsson.ejorsha.fsomobileapp.MainActivity; 
 
import java.util.List; 
 
 
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{ 
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = null; 
    private Camera camera = null; 
    int width = 720; 
    int height = 1280; 
 
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
    public CameraPreview(Context context) 
    { 
        super(context); 
 
        surfaceHolder = this.getHolder(); 
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this); 
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
 
    } 
 
    /* 
     * (non-Javadoc) 
     * @see android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceCreated(android.view.SurfaceHolder) 
     */ 
    @Override 
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    { 
        camera = Camera.open(); 
 
        setCameraDisplayOrientation(CameraActivity.this, 0, camera); 
 
 
        // Show the Camera display 
        try 
        { 
 
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); 
 
 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            this.releaseCamera(); 
        } 
 
    } 
 
    /* 
     * (non-Javadoc) 
     * @see android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceChanged(android.view.SurfaceHolder, int, int, int) 
     */ 
    @Override 
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) 
    { 
 
        // Start the preview for surfaceChanged 
        if (camera != null) 
        { 
            camera.startPreview(); 
 
 
        } 
    } 
 
    /* 
     * (non-Javadoc) 
     * @see android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceDestroyed(android.view.SurfaceHolder) 
     */ 
    @Override 
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    { 
        // Do not hold the camera during surfaceDestroyed - view should be gone 
        this.releaseCamera(); 
    } 
 
    /** 
     * Important HotFix for Google Glass (post-XE11) update 
     * @param camera Object 
     */ 
    public void setCameraParameters(Camera camera) 
    { 
        if (camera != null) 
        { 
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters(); 
            List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(); 
 
            // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app 
            Camera.Size previewSize = camera.new Size(width, height); 
 
            parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height); 
            camera.setParameters(parameters); 
            camera.startPreview(); 
        } 
    } 
 
    /** 
     * Release the camera from use 
     */ 
    public void releaseCamera() 
    { 
        if (camera != null) 
        { 
            camera.release(); 
            camera = null; 
        } 
    } 
    public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, 
                                                   int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) { 
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = 
                new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo(); 
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info); 
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay() 
                .getRotation(); 
        int degrees = 0; 
        switch (rotation) { 
            case Surface.ROTATION_0: 
                degrees = 0; 
                break; 
            case Surface.ROTATION_90: 
                degrees = 90; 
                break; 
            case Surface.ROTATION_180: 
                degrees = 180; 
                break; 
            case Surface.ROTATION_270: 
                degrees = 270; 
                break; 
        } 
 
        int result; 
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) { 
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360; 
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror 
        } else {  // back-facing 
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360; 
        } 
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result); 
 
    } 
}
```